# Generating xls file from corresponding xml

Tags: php, xml, symfony1, xls

I have an Excel (xls) template with example data. I need to prepare an Excel file with dynamically- generated data.

First, I made an XML file from the corresponding xls. 
The XML file looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Author>Op</Author>
  <LastAuthor>ufoq</LastAuthor>
  <Created>2011-11-18T06:54:25Z</Created>
  <LastSaved>2011-12-05T11:43:26Z</LastSaved>
  <Version>11.9999</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>9750</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>23310</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>480</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>405</WindowTopY>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font x:CharSet="238" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
......
```

Now I placed this content in symfony view and filled it with my generated data. 
I need to output in XML file format but I don't know how to to this.
The new file must have the same structure as the template file so I cannot make a new file from scratch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have documents in the openxml format which you can process with the [PHPExcel](http://www.phpexcel.net) library.

---

If you just want to replace some simple values in your template you could also use [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/class.domdocument) and [DOMXPath](http://docs.php.net/class.domxpath) to process the xml document, e.g.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadxml( getData() );
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$xpath->registerNamespace('o', "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office");
$xpath->registerNamespace('x', "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel");
$xpath->registerNamespace('ss', "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");
$xpath->registerNamespace('html', "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40");

foreach( $xpath->query('/ss:Workbook/o:DocumentProperties/o:LastAuthor') as $n ) {
    //echo '.';
    $text = $doc->createTextnode('SO Test');
    $n->replaceChild($text, $n->firstChild);
}
echo $doc->savexml();

function getData() {
    return <<< eox
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
 xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
 xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"
 xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
 <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
  <Author>Op</Author>
  <LastAuthor>ufoq</LastAuthor>
  <Created>2011-11-18T06:54:25Z</Created>
  <LastSaved>2011-12-05T11:43:26Z</LastSaved>
  <Version>11.9999</Version>
 </DocumentProperties>
 <ExcelWorkbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel">
  <WindowHeight>9750</WindowHeight>
  <WindowWidth>23310</WindowWidth>
  <WindowTopX>480</WindowTopX>
  <WindowTopY>405</WindowTopY>
  <ProtectStructure>False</ProtectStructure>
  <ProtectWindows>False</ProtectWindows>
 </ExcelWorkbook>
 <Styles>
  <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
   <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>
   <Borders/>
   <Font x:CharSet="238" x:Family="Swiss" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000"/>
   <Interior/>
   <NumberFormat/>
   [...]
  </Style> 
 </Styles>
</Workbook>
eox;
}
```

---

update: If you want the client to recognize the file type you have to set the content (mime) type to the approriate value, see [Office 2007 File Format MIME Types for HTTP Content Streaming](https://blogs.msdn.com/themes/blogs/generic/post.aspx?WeblogApp=vsofficedeveloper&y=2008&m=05&d=08&WeblogPostName=office-2007-open-xml-mime-types&GroupKeys=). E.g.

```
$spreadsheet = new DOMDocument;
$spreadsheet->loadxml(getData());
someProcessing($spreadsheet);
if ( headers_sent() ) {
    die('error: headers already sent');
}
header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
echo $spreadsheet->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. 
Right now i replaced data by php. But i dont know how to output this xml in excel xls format. For example user clicks on link and have a xls to download